# How to make the sliderinput independant of the reactive variables inside?

Tags: r, shiny

In this shiny app, the 3 selectInputs are linked, if we select one country in the first selectInput, the country selected do not appear in the second one, the same thing for the third.
The 2 countries not selected appear in the labels of the sliderinputs (reactive variables)
when you stare slider inputs, and you modify any country in the selectInputs above, the sliderInput do not retain the previously selected value.

My question is, how can i keep the sliderInput independant of the modifying the selectInput? Thanks for your help

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("BoxLPbilan"),
      uiOutput("BoxLPX"),
      uiOutput("BoxLPY"),
      uiOutput("Balance_country1"),
      uiOutput("Balance_country2")
    ),
    mainPanel (
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  countries<-reactive({
    c('FR','DE','BE','NL','AT')
  })
  output$BoxLPbilan <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countrybilan",label = tags$span(style="color: blue;","Select the balance country") ,countries())
  })
  liste_paysX <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
    })
  
  output$BoxLPX <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countryX", label = tags$span(style="color: red;","Select the country of the X axis"),liste_paysX())
  })
  
  liste_paysY <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countryX])
    })
  
  output$BoxLPY <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countryY", label = tags$span(style="color: red;","Select the country of the Y axis"),liste_paysY())
  })
  
  remaining_countries <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countryX])
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countryY])
      
    })

  output$Balance_country1 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "remaining_country1",
                paste(remaining_countries()[1]," balance"),
                min = -10000,
                max = 10000,
                step = 100,
                value = 0)
    
  })
  
  output$Balance_country2 <- renderUI({
    
    sliderInput(inputId = "remaining_country2",
                paste(remaining_countries()[2]," balance"),
                min = -10000,
                max = 10000,
                step = 100,
                value = 0)
    
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So you select 3 countries in 3 `selectInput` and want the two countries in `sliderInput` fixed after that?

Comment: Yes,  but if we modify the 3 countries selected in selectInput, the two countries in sliderInput change. what i want to get is to keep the slider input in the value selected if i modify the 3 countries in selectInput
Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, still not clear to me. Can you explain the expected flow to me? First we select 3 countries in `selectInput` . What is the next step?

Comment: the next step : we choose value in the slider inputs, then we change the countries selected in the beginning, so the sliderinput do not retain the values chosen.
I would like to keep the sliderInput on the value selected regardless of the countries modified

Comment: we can do it if we delete the reactive variables from the label of the sliderInput, but i want to keep the reactive variable inside and make the sliderInput Independant of it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick -

Create a `reactiveValues` to store current value of `sliderInput` and pass the default value of `sliderInput` as the stored value.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("BoxLPbilan"),
      uiOutput("BoxLPX"),
      uiOutput("BoxLPY"),
      uiOutput("Balance_country1"),
      uiOutput("Balance_country2")
    ),
    mainPanel (
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(val1 = 0, val2 = 0)
  
  countries<-reactive({
    c('FR','DE','BE','NL','AT')
  })
  output$BoxLPbilan <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countrybilan",label = tags$span(style="color: blue;","Select the balance country") ,countries())
  })
  liste_paysX <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
    })
  
  output$BoxLPX <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countryX", label = tags$span(style="color: red;","Select the country of the X axis"),liste_paysX())
  })
  
  liste_paysY <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countryX])
    })
  
  output$BoxLPY <- renderUI({
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    selectInput("countryY", label = tags$span(style="color: red;","Select the country of the Y axis"),liste_paysY())
  })
  
  remaining_countries <- reactive (
    {
      w=countries()
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countrybilan])
      w=(w[!w %in% input$countryX])
      sort(w[!w %in% input$countryY])
      
    })
  
  
  output$Balance_country1 <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "remaining_country1",
                paste(remaining_countries()[1]," balance"),
                min = -10000,
                max = 10000,
                step = 100,
                value = rv$val1)
    
  })
  
  output$Balance_country2 <- renderUI({
    
    sliderInput(inputId = "remaining_country2",
                paste(remaining_countries()[2]," balance"),
                min = -10000,
                max = 10000,
                step = 100,
                value = rv$val2)
    
  })
  
  
  observe({
    req(input$remaining_country1, input$remaining_country2)
    rv$val1 <- input$remaining_country1
    rv$val2 <- input$remaining_country2
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```